# Redirecting before executing commit()

Tags: php, redirect, transactions

Here is my script's structure:

```
try {
    $dbh_conn->beginTransaction();

    $stmt1 = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE ...");
    $stmt1->execute(array($val1));

    if ( condition 1 ) {
        $stmt2 = $dbh_conn->prepare("DELETE ...");
        $stmt2->execute(array($val2));

        header('location: ../page1');
        exit;

    } else {
        header('location: ../page2');
        exit;
    }

    $dbh_conn->commit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    $dbh_conn->rollBack();
    echo $e;

}
```

It surprisingly works .. As you see there is `if - else` statement *(always one of them will be executed)*, which both blocks *(both `if` and `else`)* have an `exit;`. Also `$dbh_conn->commit();` line is after that `if - else` statement.

Actually never those two queries should be executed. Because there is `exit;` before `commit()`. But both of queries execute as well. So how PHP compiles my script? And my script structure is ok? *(no need to change something?)*

Comment: `exit` Terminates a script right there and then! But if you have AUTO-COMMIT set, then unless you run a `rollback` data will be committed

Comment: Actually there is another possibility! Are these a MYISAM tables, because transactions dont work on MYISAM but it allows you to still use the transactional syntax

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yay .. that's the one.

Comment: Which one is the one.... _There can be only one_ as an old swordsman once said to me

Comment: My engine is MyISAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables are MYISAM then transactions dont work.

However so the mysql api does not break, the transactional functions/methods do not throw errors they just appear to be working normally, except each database update is committed as it happens.